# How to use only one glyph from textcomp

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'd like to use the symbol given by `textordmasculine` from the `textcomp` package.

But **I don't want to load** `textcomp` since it is too much and I only want that symbol (in fact I need the masculine order symbol with the underline and I didn't find this symbol except using `textcomp`).

From [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/fonts/psfonts/ts1/textcomp.sty) I found

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textordmasculine}{TS1}{'272}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textordmasculine}{TS1}
```

but have no idea how to use these lines to load that symbol.

If I use both I get

```
Encoding scheme `TS1' unknown. ...ontFamily{TS1}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font\m@ne}
Encoding scheme `TS1' unknown. \DeclareFontFamily{TS1}{phv}{}
```

Comment: You may be interested in [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: I known that there is such post but i couldn't find it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur There's no need to add the `\DeclareSymbolFont`; just the `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{myts}{}` and suitable `\DeclareFontShape` commands. Then you can define `\textordmasculine` to be `{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{myts}\selectfont\symbol{'272}}` Anyway, I don't see why not loading `textcomp`

Comment: @egreg, thanks. I don't know if `textcomp` will affect something else and since I want only one symbol I'm trying to avoid it, also I don't know if it comes with base install. Well, sorry but I'm *not* able to follow your suggestion. I tried on preamble `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{myts}{}` and `\def\textordmasculine{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{myts}\selectfont\symbol{'272}}` but it does not work.

Comment: @Sigur textcomp is part of the latex core release, it is like article class, a mandated part of any latex installation.

Comment: @Sigur You need to add also the `\DeclareFontShape` commands relative to the fonts you need; it's definitely easier to load `textcomp`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Full `textcomp`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}   
\begin{document}
\textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

Package `textcomp` takes care of font families that do not support the full range of encoding TS1 by a concept of "subencoding".

### Full encoding TS1 without `textcomp`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TS1,OT1]{fontenc}% or T1 instead of OT1
\begin{document}
\textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

That assumes that the used font supports *all* symbols of TS1. However, `\textordmasculine` is usually not missing. But other symbols like `\textbullet` are redefined to use TS1 encoding.

### Partial encoding TS1 with `\textordmasculine`

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{TS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textordmasculine}{TS1}{186}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textordmasculine}{TS1}

\begin{document}
\textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

Then the symbol is still defined using LaTeX's NFSS2. That means font size commands, changing font attributes (`\textbf`, …) work. But `\textbullet` is not redefined.

### Font loading via plain TeX command

If you need the symbol in one size and shape only, then you could also load the font directly. Then first create a MWE for the symbol with using `textcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[loading]{tracefnt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

Make sure, that the font sizes and families are correct:

- Correct size option for the document class (`10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt`).
- The MWE contains all other font packages (`lmodern`, `mathptx`, …).

Then run the MWE through LaTeX and look for the following information of `tracefnt`:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `tcrm1000 at10.0pt' loaded as
(Font)              TS1/cmr/m/n/10  on input line 6.
```

`tcrm1000 at10.0pt` can be different depending on the font and size settings. It is the data we need for `\newfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newfont{\fonttextcomp}{tcrm1000 at10.0pt}
% \providecommand for the case `textcomp` is loaded.
\providecommand*{\textordmasculine}{%
  \begingroup\fonttextcomp\symbol{186}\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\textordmasculine
\end{document}
```

Limitation: The symbol will not resize or is affected by `\textbf` etc. Each variant requires a new font and macro.

### Summary

Because the latest method is cumbersome and has serious limitations, I would recommend the third method (or one of the first three methods).

### Result

> [image: Result]

Comment: Method three is basically what I do in `siunitx` to load a few required symbols without having to require `textcomp`.

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation. How did you know that the symbol number would be 186?

Comment: @Sigur: I have looked it up in `ts1enc.def`.