# Use only one character of any package

Tags: hyperref, symbols, characters

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
\%

‰

@ % <-- use only \usepackage{mathptmx}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use only one character of any package? I want to use that package @ character as in the example. There are questions I think are similar. But it was a little complicated to me. Can you help me?

Related1: [How to use only one glyph from textcomp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123813/33075)

Related2: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/33075)

Comment: I assume you're wanting to use one character from the font, **and not import the rest of the font into your pdf**?  Or are you getting tripped up because `@` is a special character and must be typed differently?

Comment: My purpose is to use only the `\usepackage{mathptmx}` package in the entire `@` character. I hope I can tell you right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to handle `T1` encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand\at{{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ztmcm}\selectfont@}}
\begin{document}
@\at@
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Steven B. Segletes: Does not work when A `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{lmodern}`  is added.

Comment: @Özgür I have addressed the issue with a revision.

Comment: It works as it should be.