# Deformat stix package

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols, stix

I am working on a combinatorial games project which requires use of the ⧾ symbol (this looks a lot like a plus, but isn't). The only package (according to the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list) which offers this symbol is the `stix` package, using the command `\tplus`. However, importing the stix package makes the formatting for the rest of the document look bad, and I would prefer to change that. A bunch of searching has proved relatively fruitless.

So, I need either a header which provides the full default LaTeX formatting, or a way of importing *just* this symbol from the `stix` package. No MWE is provided, as through my testing the `stix` package is the only variable here.

Comment: What exactly does "formatting for the rest of the document look bad" refer to here? The text surrounding the math environments? If so, you could try `\usepackage[notext]{stix2}` instead.

Comment: why not simply use a small + so it matches the font you are using? But otherwise, the question is a duplicate of several similar ones, eg  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403500/use-only-one-character-of-any-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only complication is that `stix2` defines font its own font encodings. Here are the steps.

#### 1. Identify the character

In `stix2.sty`, look for `\tplus` to find

```
\stix@MathSymbol{\tplus}                    {\mathbin}  {symbols2}{"EB}
```

#### 2. Find the font parameters

Look for `symbols2` to find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols2}      {LS1}{stix2frak} {m} {n}
```

#### 3. Find the font encoding setup

Look for `LS1` to find

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
```

Only the first and third lines are needed.

#### 4. Make up the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols2}{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tplus}{\mathbin}{symbols2}{"EB}

\begin{document}

$a+b\tplus c\tplus\dots\tplus z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also avoid to waste a math group just for one symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\tplus}{\DOTSB\tplusbin}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tplusbin}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}\symbol{"EB}}}%
}

\begin{document}

$a+b\tplus c\tplus\dots\tplus z$

\end{document}
```